# Filling TableAdapter with background worker in form initialize

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am using the background worker to fill TableAdapter with is Binded to Grid in form initialize because there are many records to load  So, following are my codes but it raise an error in Program.cs file !!! plz help me to handle background worker in order to fill my TableAdapter.

```
public OrderFRM()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
     }

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.ordersTableAdapter.FillByFinancialPeriodFK(this.oxygenDataSet.Orders, PublicClass.FinancialFK);


        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, x.Message + "\n" + x.StackTrace, x.TargetSite.Name, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Error Message :
[image]

detail error is:[image]

Notice,this is the stack trace message :

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at OXYGEN.Program.Main() in D:\Oxygen\OXYGEN\OXYGEN\Program.cs:line 19
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Read the InnerException.

Comment: there is only gridview on my form !!!

Comment: Read the _exception's_ InnerException.  (in View Detail)

Comment: @SLaks I read the InnerException and edit the post but could'nt understand what is the solution :(

Comment: Read the InnerException's stack trace.

Comment: can't understand what does it mean , If you know please don't hesitate .

Comment: The stack trace tells you which line of your code is broken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62127/discussion-between-franchesco-totti-and-slaks).

Comment: somebody , help plz??

Comment: You still need to read the inner exception stack trace and find out where the problem is.